# How to load pickle(.pkl) file from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pickle

I have successfully read the csv file from Amazon S3. But I have .pkl file of sentiment model. I want to load this .pkl file to predict sentiment. Here is my code -

```
import cPickle
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import boto3.session

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='eu-central-1')
s3client = session.client('s3', config= boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'),aws_access_key_id='my-ACCESS-KEY-ID',
         aws_secret_access_key='my-ACCESS-KEY')

response = s3client.get_object(Bucket='sentiment-data', Key='positive_model_data.pkl')

nb_detector = cPickle.load(open(response['Body']))
nb_predict = nb_detector.predict('food is very good')[0]
print nb_predict
```

Error
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, StreamingBody found

How to load pickel file from S3???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cPickle.load()` method requires a file. You need to use `loads` method instead of `load`. `loads` requires string data, as stated in the error message. However, `response['Body']` gives you `StreamingBody`. `StreamingBody` has a method named `read` which can return string content.

```
...
body_string = response['Body'].read()
positive_model_data = cPickle.loads(body_string)
print positive_model_data
...
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: The first line should be `body_string = response['Body'].read()` not `...ready()`, right?

Comment: body_string = response['Body'].read()
nb_detector = cPickle.loads(body_string)
nb_predict = nb_detector.predict('food is very good')[0]
print nb_predict

Comment: It gives me Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received Error

Answer (score 0):

boto3 client returns a streaming body type when you subscript using `['Body']`
you need to first read the byte content in the streaming body before loading it.
This is a working implementation using your code subsection.

```
s3_data = response['Body'].read() #read byte data

nb_detector = pickle.load(s3_data) #load pickle data

nb_predict = nb_detector.predict('food is very good')[0]
print(nb_predict)
```